# RegExp to match lonely or single uppercase letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a pipe in angular, but I cannot seem to wrap my head around regular expressions.

I am trying to match only lonely or single uppercase letters and split them.
Let us say for instance I have the following:

`thisIsAnApple` should return `[this, Is, An, Apple]`

`thisIsAString` should return `[this, Is, AString]`

`BB88GGFR` should return `[BB88GGFR]`

So the plan is to match a capital letter if it is not accompanied by another capital letter.

This is what I have come up with:

```
const regExr = new RegExp(/(?=[A-Z])(?![A-Z]{2,})/g);
let split = string.split(regExr);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
string.split(/(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/)
```

Or, to support all Unicode letters:

```
string.split(/(?<=\p{Ll})(?=\p{Lu})/u)
```

Basically, you match an empty string between a lowercase and an uppercase letter.

JS demo:

```js
const strings = ['thisIsAnApple', 'thisIsAString', 'BB88GGFR'];
const regex = /(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/;
for (let s of strings) {
  console.log(s, '=>', s.split(regex));
}
```

JS demo #2:

```js
const strings = ['thisIsĄnApple', 'этоСТрокаТакая', 'BB88GGFR'];
const regex = /(?<=\p{Ll})(?=\p{Lu})/u;
for (let s of strings) {
  console.log(s, '=>', s.split(regex));
}
```

Comment: Wow.  Thank you so much for the explanation